# how to make readfield read next field

Tags: c#, textfieldparser

My csv file contains 8 columns and 300k rows.Here is an example of my csv file
"0195153448";"Classical Mythology";"Mark P. O. Morford";"2002";"Oxford University Press";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0195153448.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"
"0002005018";"Clara Callan";"Richard Bruce Wright";"2001";"HarperFlamingo Canada";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.THUMBZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.MZZZZZZZ.jpg";"http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0002005018.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg"

Now i have this code for reading

```
string path = @"C:\Users\SEMRUK\Desktop\exceller\kitaplik.csv";
public DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string PathFile)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

        TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(PathFile);

                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] {";"});
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }               
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                MessageBox.Show(fieldData[i]);
                    }
            csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);

        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

This way i can read the first 8 rows.But i can't read anything after that.It just reads first 8.How can i tell the code that it should read after tab too.I tried adding \t to the setdelimiters but didn't work.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string path = "your_file_path";

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

            string[] parsedText= text.Split(';');

            foreach (var item in parsedText)
            {
                //do some
            }

        }
```

Comment: 20 hours of internet search did not give me this simple answer you did.So simple yet hard to find.Thank you good sir.Lots of love.